# How do I search for matching values in a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range in Excel that looks like this:

```
  | Symptom       | Number|  
1 | back pain     | 7     |  
2 | neck pain     | 583   |  
3 | shoulder pain | 5098  |  
4 | eye pain      | 23467 |  
5 | back pain     | 23    |  
6 | neck pain     | 65756 |  
7 | shoulder pain | 234   |  
8 | eye pain      | 98    |
```

I want the values in Number to be compared against each other based on the value in Symptom. For example, back pain appears in Symptom twice, so I want 23 compared against 7. Upon determining which is larger, I want the second instance of the Symptom to be colored red or green, red if its Number is larger than the first instance, green if it's smaller.

Initially I tried writing code with 2 ranges, one with the first instance of each Symptom, and another range with the second instance of each Symptom. I tried writing a For Each loop within a For Each loop, but that's not allowed, so I'm stuck as to how to proceed. My code:

```
Sub RankColor()
    Dim SelecRng As Range
    Dim OrgNumOld As Integer
    Dim SearchTerm As String

    Set SelecRngOld = Application.Selection
    Set SelecRngOld = Application.InputBox("Range", SelecRng, Type:=8)

    Set SelecRngNew = Application.Selection
    Set SelecRngNew = Application.InputBox("Range", SelecRng, Type:=8)

    For Each cell In SelecRngOld
    Set SearchTerm = cell.Value
    OrgNumOld = Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value
        For Each cell in SelecRngNew
            If Cells(cell.Row, 2) > OrgNumOld Then 'Compares the
            Cells(cell.Row, 2).Color = RGB(256, 0, 0)
            ElseIf Cells(cell.Row, 2) > OrgNumOld Then
            Cells(cell.Row, 2).Color = RGB(0, 256, 0)
            End If
        End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if there's more than two listings? Are they each red or green based on the first instance of the symptom, or only compared to the last found instance?

Comment: There will only ever be 2 listings of a particular symptom. If someone could help me write code that could handle more than 2 listings, that's fine, but it's not relevant to this code's use case.

Answer (score 2):

Create two conditional formatting rules.

Red:

```
=AND(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A1,$A:$A,0))<$B1,MATCH($A1,$A:$A,0)<>ROW())
```

Green:

```
=AND(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A1,$A:$A,0))>$B1,MATCH($A1,$A:$A,0)<>ROW())
```

Both should Apply to `$B:$B`

[image]